# Two dictionaries in python with different results

Tags: python, dictionary

I dont understand why the same approach works for the one function and dictionary and it doesn´t for the second one, even though I just "copied" it.

```
allGuests = {"Alice": {"apples": 5, "pretzels": 12}, "Bob": {"ham sandwiches": 3, "apples": 2}, "Carol": {"cups": 3, "apple pies": 1}}
allCalories = {"apples": {"Calories": 100, "fat": 10}, "pretzels": {"Calories": 200, "fat": 20}, "ham sandwiches": {"Calories": 300, "fat": 30}, "cups": {"Calories": 0, "fat": 0}, "apple pies": {"Calories": 500, "fat": 50}}

def totalBrought(guests, item): 
    numBrought = 0              
    for k, v in guests.items(): 


        numBrought = numBrought + v.get(item, 0) 
    return numBrought

def totalCalories(dish, calories):
    cal = 0
    for k, v in dish.items():
        cal = cal + v.get(calories, 0)
    return cal

print(" Number of Things being brought: ")
print(" - Apples " + str(totalBrought(allGuests, "apples")))
print(" Calories of apples " + str(totalCalories(allCalories, "apples")))
print(" - Cups " + str(totalBrought(allGuests, "cups")))    
print(" - Cakes " + str(totalBrought(allGuests, "cakes")))
print(" - Ham Sandwiches " + str(totalBrought(allGuests, "ham sandwiches")))
print(" - Apple Pies " + str(totalBrought(allGuests, "apple pies")))
```

The (wrong) outcome is:

```
Number of Things being brought: 
- Apples 7
Calories of apples 0
- Cups 3
- Cakes 0
- Ham Sandwiches 3
- Apple Pies 1
```

Can anyone explain to me why it doesn´t work? Seems like a simple logical gap by a python beginner....
Thanks in advance!

Comment: so, what is the "right" outcome?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bug lies here:

```
def totalCalories(dish, calories):
    cal = 0
    for k, v in dish.items():
        cal = cal + v.get(calories, 0)
    return cal
```

You iterate over each item in turn, like `{"Calories": 100, "fat": 10}`, `{"Calories": 200, "fat": 20}`, and so on, by virtue of your loop. But you're querying for `'apples'` which doesn't exist, and you keep adding 0.

You've already got the key! You have no need to iterate over the `dict` again. That defeats its purpose.

You can simply do:

```
def totalCalories(dish, calories):
    return dish[calories]["Calories"]
```

I believe you've misnamed your variables, which is confusing you. Try this:

```
def totalCalories(calorie_dict, item):
    return calorie_dict[item]["Calories"]
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer gave me the needed "aha effect" to realize my mistake. I corrected it myself then and expanded the whole idea bit so thanks for explaining!!

Comment: @marvinb89 Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

This also seems like a good use case to be using a `Counter` object from the `Collections` module. It'll allow you to calculate all frequencies of the various food items in a single call versus requiring a separate function call per food item.

```
# Python 2.7 Syntax
from collections import Counter
allGuests = {"Alice": {"apples": 5, "pretzels": 12}, "Bob": {"ham sandwiches": 3, "apples": 2}, "Carol": {"cups": 3, "apple pies": 1}}

def totalBrought(guests):
    food_counter = Counter()
    for k,v in guests.iteritems():
        food_counter.update(v)
    return food_counter

print totalBrought(allGuests)
>> Counter({'pretzels': 12, 'apples': 7, 'cups': 3, 'ham sandwiches': 3, 'apple pies': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I changed the namings for a better understanding (see below).
There might be more sophisticated solutions but I like to stick to the "initial" approach since I am still a beginner and dont want to skip topics and just adapt the more sophisticated ways.

```
allCalories = {"apples": {"Calories apples": 80, "Fat apples": 2}, "pretzels": 
              {"Calories pretzels": 200, "Fat pretzels": 20},"ham sandwiches": 
              {"Calories ham sandwiches": 300, "Fat ham sandwiches":30}"cups":
              {"Calories cups": 0, "Fat Cups": 0},"apple pies": 
              {"Calories apple pies": 500, "Fat apple pies": 50}}
```

And then for example:

```
print(" -> Total Calories of Apples " + 
str(totalCalories(allCalories,"Calories apples")*
(totalBrought(allGuests,"apples"))))
```

I also added a few other lines so the outcome now looks like this:

```
Number, Calories and Fat of Things being brought: 
- Apples 7
-> Total Calories of Apples 560
-> Total Fat of Apples 14 Gramm
- Pretzels 12
-> Total Calories of Pretzels 2400
-> Total Fat of Pretzels 240 Gramm
- Cups 3
-> Total Calories of Cups 0
-> Total Fat of Cups 0 Gramm
- Cakes 0
-> Total Calories of Cakes 0
-> Total Fat of Cakes 0 Gramm
- Ham Sandwiches 3
-> Total Calories of Ham Sandwiches 900
-> Total Fat of Ham Sandwiches 90 Gramm
- Apple Pies 3
-> Total Calories of Apple Pies 1500
-> Total Fat of Apple Pies 150 Gramm
==>> Total Calories of Things being brought: 5360
==>> Total Fat of Things being brought: 494
```